# Validating Top Level Domains with Zend 1

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am having a problem with [Validating Top Level Domains](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.email-address.html#validating-top-level-domains). Basically, anything with `.tech` as the TLD is failing the email validation.

I have inherited this project and don't know Zend very well but I have traced the problem back to the hostname not being valid [here is the code on GitHub](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Validate/EmailAddress.php#L557-L572);

```
    // Match hostname part
    if ($this->_options['domain']) {
        $hostname = $this->_validateHostnamePart();
    }

    $local = $this->_validateLocalPart();

    // If both parts valid, return true
    if ($local && $length) {
        if (($this->_options['domain'] && $hostname) || !$this->_options['domain']) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
```

Now, I have some local code here;

```
class Form_InviteToSpaceForm extends Twitter_Bootstrap_Form_Horizontal
{

    public function init()
    {

        // Set the method for the display form to POST
        $this->setMethod('post');
        $this->setAction('/team');

        $this->addElement('textarea', 'email', array(
            'label'       => 'Email addresses',
            'dimension' => 10,
            'required'    => true,
            'placeholder' => "person1@email.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                person2@email.com",//line breaks don't work on placeholders, have to force line wrap with spaces
            'filters'     => array('StringTrim'),
            'validators' => array(
                array('validator' => 'NotEmpty'),
                array('validator' => 'EmailAddress', 'options' => array('messages' => array('emailAddressInvalidFormat' => 'Incorrect email address specified.')))
            )
        ));
```

If I comment out the line with the last `array('messages' => array('emailAddressInvalidFormat' => 'Incorrect email address specified.')))` then this whole validation is avoided. But I don't want to avoid using this. I just want to be able to extend and add `.tech` or whatever else comes up from genuine clients. How can I do this with Zend?

Comment: "By default a hostname will be checked against a list of known TLDs" - sounds like a bad design - but the docs you linked to describe how to switch it off.

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom validator extended from Zend validator

```
class My_Validate_Hostname extends Zend_Validate_Hostname
{
    public function __construct($options = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($options);
        $this->_validTlds = array_merge($this->_validTlds, array('tech'));
    }
}
```

and pass it to email validator

```
$emailValidator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress(array('messages' => array('emailAddressInvalidFormat' => 'Incorrect email address specified.')));
$emailValidator->setHostnameValidator(new My_Validate_Hostname());
....
$this->addElement('textarea', 'email', array(
            'label'       => 'Email addresses',
            'dimension' => 10,
            'required'    => true,
            'placeholder' => "person1@email.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                person2@email.com",//line breaks don't work on placeholders, have to force line wrap with spaces
            'filters'     => array('StringTrim'),
            'validators' => array(
                array('validator' => 'NotEmpty'),
            )
        ))->addValidator($emailValidator);
```

Comment: Is it possible to instruct the default email validator to ALWAYS use the custom hostname validator?